# Angular 5 reactive form - disable one radio option in radio group

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a radio group which uses the same form control for each option. Is it possible to disable just the red radio button? I know you can set the disabled flag on the **color**  form control but this will disabled all radio buttons.

```
<fieldset [formGroup]="colorForm">
    <legend>
      Choose color
    </legend>

<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="red" formControlName="color">
    Red
  </label>
</div>

<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="green" formControlName="color">
    Green
  </label>
</div>

<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="blue" formControlName="color">
    Blue
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try this out

```
 <input type="radio" [attr.disabled]="propertyName === false || null"" 
  value="red" formControlName="color">
```

propertyName i.e. value comes from components.ts file

Comment: Thanks Pranay Rana. That is basically the same thing I just came up with. It looks like it is working.